# How can I output residuals from multiple models in a single new data frame using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, lme4, genetics

I would like to run multiple regression models for a static set of independent variables against multiple different dependent variables and output the residuals into a new file that looks like...

```
SampleID     site_residual1    site_residual2    site_residual3
F001         0.003             0.988             0.776
F001         0.002             0.876             0.665
F002         0.134             0.234             0.786
...
```

I have been using the following code to get a single residual output, but have been unsuccessful in implementing a loop that will run through all of my sites.

```
infile = sprintf("/path/siteinput.txt.gz")
```

infile looks like...

```
SampleID     site1  site2   site3   etc...
F001         0.003  0.988   0.776   etc...
F001         0.002  0.876   0.665   etc...
F002         0.134  0.234   0.786   etc...
...
```

...

```
pheno = read.table("/path/pheno_covar.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
```

pheno looks like...

```
SampleID     indep1 indep2  indep3  chip1   etc...
F001         0.003  0.988   0.776   2       etc...
F001         0.002  0.876   0.665   2       etc...
F002         0.134  0.234   0.786   1       etc...
...
```

...

```
residfile = sprintf("/path/test_resid_out.txt")

library(lme4)

beta = read.table(infile, header=T, sep="\t")

merged = merge(beta, pheno, by="SampleID")

site<-merged$site1
chip <- as.factor(merged$chip1)

model1 <- lmer (formula= site ~ indep1 +indep2 + indep3 + (1|chip), data=merged)

print(summary(model1))
print(resid(model1))

site1_resid = resid(model1, na.action=na.exclude)

residout<-(data.frame(SampleID, site1_resid))
write.table(residout, file=residfile, sep="\t", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

And my output looks like...

```
SampleID    site1_resid
F001        0.0110177454696274
F002        0.0923483180517723
F003        0.103686493563883
F004        -0.106193404096636
F005        -0.124621172636435
....
```

...

So, I am really looking for a way to run model1 for each site in my "infile" and output all residuals into a new file. Also, I would like to have the column header to include the original name of the "site". I do have some missing information in (all covariates are complete, but some sites are missing for some IDs).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `broom` package which is designed for such cases: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Broom does look useful for adding residuals to the original dataframe, but I am really interested in creating a new dataframe with residual columns for each outcome variable. I don't see this functionality in the Broom package, but maybe I am missing this somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `magrittr` pipes (`%>%`) to make it easier to read (not necessary, though):

```
library(magrittr)
names(beta) %>% 
  setdiff("SampleID") %>% 
  setNames(., .) %>% 
  lapply(function(x) {
    model <- lmer(data = merged, formula = paste(x, "~ indep1 +indep2 + indep3 + (1|chip)"))
    # print(summary(model))
    # print(resid(model))
    resid(model, na.action=na.exclude)
  }) %>% 
  c(list(SampleID = merged$SampleID), .) %>% 
  do.call(what = "data.frame")
```

(On a side note, it worries me that you have duplicate `SampleID`s. Is it intended? If yes, are you sure you want to `merge()` by `SampleID`? Would you not rather do `cbind(beta, pheno[, - 1, drop = FALSE])`?)

Comment: The SampleIDs should not contain duplicates, but produce a 1:1 merge. However, they are sorted differently in the two files.

Comment: Thanks, @a-p-o-m. When I apply your suggestions I get the following error...    `Error in data.frame(SampleID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2684, 2676
Calls: %>% ... withVisible -> <Anonymous> -> do.call -> data.frame
Execution halted`. I assume this comes from missing values for some of the sites, but I am unclear on why `na.action=na.exclude` does not take care of this issue. Any additional suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, @Apom. I was able to get it working after `na.action=na.exclude` into the model statement instead of `resid`.